# How to calculate rating of merchant in e-commerce

Tags: microeconomics

Could u help me to solve this case? Here's the case.. The first, There are 3 aspects for calculate Rating of each merchant. The scale of rating is from 1 until n ( Based on sum of Merchants). The first aspect is product's price and proportion of this price is 50% from 100%. The second aspect is product's Quality and proportion of this quality is 25 % from 100%. The last aspect is sum of product which is already sold and proportion of this quality is 25% from 100%. The sum of proportion from those aspects are 100%.

here is the simulation.. Merchant A is already join e-commerce for 3 years and the price of their product is 65 dollars.they are already fulfill those aspects that mentioned earlier. Merchant B is already join e-commerce for 4 years and the price of their product is 70 dollars. The position of product is affected from rating merchant. the cheap price and fulfill those aspects perfectly, it'd be get the first position in website e-commerce. so the simulation would be merchant A (1) is the first position and merchant B(2) is the second position.

If there are 2 new merchants which have the same price(both 50 Dollars) & same products but more cheaper that merchant A and B, and then those new merchant haven't fulfill the second and the third aspects, just fulfill the first aspect, how should we calculate the ratings? are there any aspect that needed to calculate this ratings?

Comment: Please spend more effort on phrasing your question, I only have the vaguest idea what exactly it is you are asking.